# Wakeup HDMI display from standby without interrupting blank screen

Tags: hdmi, xorg

I've a HDMI display attached to a RasperryPi 4. After few minutes, first a blank screen is activated, then the display goes into standby.

I want to wakeup the display from standby (by a sensor via bash script) but don't interrupt the blank screen.

I know wakeup is possible with:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 xset dpms force on
```

but is also interrupts the blank screen.

Comment: why do you want to do that? ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CEC library and issue:

```
echo "on 0" | cec-client -s
```

To install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install cec-utils
```

(Note I've followed the RPF guide using full-upgrade but see [here](https://embeddedinventor.com/apt-upgrade-vs-full-upgrade-differences-explained-for-beginners/) for a discussion on upgrade vs full-upgrade)

Comment: Seems my display has no cec support: err 1 "autodetect FAILED".